# Logic behind Flatten and Append to in Module

Tags: function-construction

I have a list(kicks), and a function(fix). I am aware of the problem using Loop and Append or AppendTo. My question is why does the Flatten produce the desired output.

List:

```
kicks = {6.28992, 1.78953, 4.67832, 3.85717, 4.15561, 7.9862, 8.02365,
         2.62077, 5.89348, 6.50246}
```

Function:

```
 fix[list_] := Module[{xos, comp, ct},
    comp = {};
    xos = If[list > 7, AppendTo[comp, list]];
    ct = Flatten[comp]]

fix[#] & /@ kicks


Output: {{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {7.9862}, {8.02365}, {}, {}, {}}
```

Desired output:

```
{7.9862, 8.02365}
```

I want to understand why Flatten in this case does not work, and how to solve it while using Module.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are applying `Flatten` inside the function that you map.  Your flattened lists will still have the head `List`, and will produce the output you show.  Instead you must either:

- `Flatten` outside the function after mapping
- Use [`Sequence`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Sequence.html) as the head of the returned expression so that these are effectively flattened automatically.

The first is simply:

```
fix /@ kicks // Flatten
```

> ```
> {7.9862, 8.02365}
> ```

The second would be something like:

```
fix2[list_] :=
 Module[{comp},
  comp = {};
  If[list > 7, comp = {comp, list}];
  Sequence @@ Flatten[comp]
 ]

fix2 /@ kicks
```

> ```
> {7.9862, 8.02365}
> ```

However, using this function outside of `Map` may cause strange results as `Sequence` is returned to the top level (and may be caught by things like `$PrePrint` on the way).

**Notes:**

- You do not need to embed `fix` in a new [`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Function.html) before mapping it: simply write `fix /@ kicks`
- I presume that being aware of the problem with `AppendTo` you wanted a linked-lists format, so I included that in my `fix2` example.

Comment: Sequence thats what I was looking for! Great thank you!

Comment: @ALEXANDER You're welcome.

Comment: The "`AppendTo` problem" is `AppendTo` copies the list to generate the answer, right?

Comment: @Hector every time you change the length of a list you cause the underlying (low level) array to be reallocated, therefore append operations take time proportional to the length of the list.  You can therefore make fast appends by using the format `list = {list, new}` or `list = {new, list}`, and then flattening at the end.  Also see `Sow` and `Reap`, and ``Internal`Bag`` and related functions (search).